# How many "How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?" questions are eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Everyone knows Java has garbage collection but apparently no one knows how it works so we keep seeing variations of the question "How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?". Here are a few:

- [How many objects in this Java code is eligible for Garbage Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083805/how-many-objects-in-this-java-code-is-eligible-for-garbage-collection)
- [Java job interview. How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457137/java-job-interview-how-many-objects-are-eligible-for-garbage-collection)
- [How many objects will be eligible for garbage collection after executing "m1=null; m2=null;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258627/how-many-objects-will-be-eligible-for-garbage-collection-after-executing-m1-nul)
- [How many objects are eligible for garbage collector when we create an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543939/how-many-objects-are-eligible-for-garbage-collector-when-we-create-an-array-of-a)
- [SCJP Mock Question: How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801732/scjp-mock-question-how-many-objects-are-eligible-for-garbage-collection)
- [How many objects will be eligible for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250291/how-many-objects-will-be-eligible-for-garbage-collection)
- [Objects eligible for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564137/objects-eligible-for-garbage-collection)
- [How many objects are eligible for garbage collector in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318630/how-many-objects-are-eligible-for-garbage-collector-in-this-example)
- [Interview question: Objects eligible for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299604/interview-question-objects-eligible-for-garbage-collection)

All of these have different examples that ask about garbage collection of objects of type `String` and other custom types, assignment of reference values and `null` to local, instance, and class variables, etc.

There is no variation of these concepts (except some edge cases with specific JVM implementations) that doesn't reduce to the same issue. They can **all** be answered by the question *What makes an object eligible for garbage collection?* for which I have yet to find a (satisfactory) canonical post. If you have one, please provide a link to it.

What's worse, a lot of the answers contain misleading information. A lot of these have collected considerable upvotes making it hard to signal to others that they are wrong (yes, yes, downvote and comment and Stack Overflow will work out over time).

Is there a use for all of these or should we create a canonical as mentioned above?

I'm aiming to clean these up very soon and I'd like some direction.

Comment: Perhaps you should avoid creating new canonicals and instead add a topic to SO/docs covering this.

Comment: @bwoebi Until we can use a doc as a duplicate target, that will have minimal effect, imo.

Comment: Uhhh, let's just assume the devs will add this in a short timeframe…

Comment: My personal beef with those questions, is that [they don't really make any sense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26263929/1743880). Even reasoning on scope [can lead to trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/1743880) and objects can be garbage collected [even if referenced by local var](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645534/1743880). The canonical would have to cover a lot of aspects.

Comment: @Tunaki That's the _misleading_ part. Yeah, the canonical would have to explain that scope is a compile time concept. Shall we make a list of what should be covered?

Comment: Perhaps create a canonical in Java that covers "what does it mean an object is eligible for garbage collection?" It is possible given enough system resource that the gc never runs for small sets of memory use.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure, we can make a community-wiki answer listing things to consider. I can't find a proper canonical out there either.

Comment: typo in title, should read "How many “How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?” questions are eligible for _garbage collection_?"

Comment: @Tunaki Add below? I can't find something in the specs that clearly states that a finalizer can only be run on objects that are not _reachable_. I need a break.

Comment: @gnat I feel like someone posts one of these on meta every day. The question we should really be asking ourselves is, *How many "How many 'How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?' questions are eligible for garbage collection?" questions are eligible for garbage collection?*

Answer (score 12):

A canonical should include a description of the following (please add what you think is relevant):

- [JVMS details about the Heap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3)

  > The heap is created on virtual machine start-up. Heap storage for objects is reclaimed by an automatic storage management system (known as a garbage collector); objects are never explicitly deallocated. The Java Virtual Machine assumes no particular type of automatic storage management system, and the storage management technique may be chosen according to the implementor's system requirements.
- [Finalization in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6)

  > - Before the storage for an object is reclaimed by the garbage collector, the Java Virtual Machine will invoke the finalizer of that object.
  > - The Java programming language does not specify how soon a finalizer will be invoked, except to say that it will happen before the storage for the object is reused.
  > - A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.

More entries in JLS

- [Organization of the Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.1)

  > When an object is no longer referenced, it may be reclaimed by the garbage collector. If an object declares a finalizer, the finalizer is executed before the object is reclaimed to give the object a last chance to clean up resources that would not otherwise be released. When a class is no longer needed, it may be unloaded.

  Relevant SO post: [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376768/can-java-finalize-an-object-when-it-is-still-in-scope)